# How to enable keyboard event after customizing my own snippet in aptana3?

Tags: javascript, ruby, code-snippets, aptana3

I have a custom snippet, **snippets.rb** in the **JavaScript bubble project**. And I could see my definition in the snippets view after restarting the Aptana, but `double click` is the only trigger. How do I enable the keyboard trigger.

Comment: It would help to see your code. If you are looking for a snippet trigger like `c)tab`, you will need a line like `s.trigger = 'c)'`, if you want a key combination like `CTRL+ALT+H`, you will need to make a wrapper command for your snippet. Examples can be found throughout the included bundles. Find one that does what you want and see how it is coded.

Comment: I have defined the line `s.trigger="log"` and now I solved the problem in my personal compuator, but this is not useful for the compuator of my company, I guess it's may be the keyboard shortcuts conflix.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. I truly definited a line `s.trigger="log"` in the `snippets.rb` file, but I forgot to add the difinition `console_log: "Console log"` in the `PROJECT/config/locales/en.yml`, this is the way to enable the keyboard shortcut.